# Undefined symbol __istype with /opt/local/bin/g++?

Tags: c++, g++, clang, clang++

When I compile my program with this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run
```

I get this error (not sure since I don't use any code with `__istype` in it):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__istype(int, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::ctype<char>::is(unsigned long, char) const in ccuyHAvU.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched and cannot find an answer. A suggestion was to include the full path to `libstdc++.a`, but that did nothing:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run /opt/local/lib/gcc48/libstdc++.a
```

But, when I compile with `clang++` on my machine, the program does compile and work.

For this particular project, I must use `g++` (the servers do not have clang++, but do have g++ v4.8). Is there anything I can do?

Edit: I tried `which g++` to see where my installation of `g++` is located. I then ran the command `/opt/local/bin/g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run`, but it also ends up giving the same error.

Comment: As it seems you have a custom installation of GCC, it's very likely that the `g++` program you run is from the system and not the one you installed, which might confuse things. Try e.g. `which g++` to see which path the program you run is in.

Comment: Running `which g++` gives that it is in `/opt/local/bin/`. Is there a difference? (Still getting the same error even with using this `g++`).

Comment: Yes, but are you really invoking the custom installed `g++` in `/opt/local/bin` or the system installed `g++`? Are you *actually* writing e.g. `/opt/local/bin/g++ ...`?

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. My full command is `/opt/local/bin/g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run`. It also gives the same error.

Comment: Okay. You might want to edit the question to include that information.

Comment: You’re using OS X 10.9 and GCC 4.x installed via Homebrew, right?

Comment: You should add "-v" to your call. Maybe, you'll get additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with your version glicxx, I hope this link can help you. http://psykil.livejournal.com/337476.html